# go-qml: как получить значения текстовых полей?

Tags: golang, qml

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как лучше всего получить значение из qml?
Предлагался вариант создавать структуру и передавать ее форме:
main.go
...
import "gopkg.in/qml.v1"

```
type QMLBridge struct {
    Login string
    Password string
    Captcha string
}

func (b *QMLBridge) Set(login string, password string, captcha string) {
//что то как-то...
}

func main(){

    engine := qml.NewEngine()

// чтобы окно закрывалось по Qt.quit() в qml
    engine.On("quit", func() {
            os.Exit(0)
    })

    controls, err := engine.LoadFile("main.qml")
    context := engine.Context()

// передаем нашу структуру переменную bridge
    context.SetVar("bridge", &QMLBridge{})

    window := controls.CreateWindow(nil)
    window.Show()
    window.Wait()

}
```

...

в main.qml

```
...

TextFiled{id: edLogin}
TextFiled{id: edPass}

    button  {
    onClicked: {
// исполнение Set из main.go
        bridge.set(edLogin.text, edPass.text);
        Qt.quit();
    }
    }
...
```

И непонятно, как работать со значениями *edLogin* и *edPass*. У меня получается в теле func Set только вносить значения в глобальные переменные, чтобы обрабатывать данные из формы qml. Но мне это кажется неправильным.
Другая проблема, что после исполнения *bridge.set(edLogin.text, edPass.text)* команда Qt.quit() перестает работать вообще. Если bridge.set не исполняется, то Qt.quit() без проблем закрывает

Comment: Тело Set нельзя ли увидеть?

Comment: Должно быть типа: `b.Login = login; b.Password = password; b.Captcha = captcha; qml.Changed( b, &b.Login ); qml.Changed( b, &b.Password ); qml.Changed( b, &b.Captcha );` В общем `qml.Changed()` вызывается только для тех полей, которые Вы хотите, чтобы изменились и в qml-файле (чтобы они соответствовали go-значениям).

Comment: Во-первых, нельзя совмещать два вопроса в одно. Во-вторых, что не так? Что конкретно не так? В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю механики, но воспроизвести проблемы не удалось. Прилагаю свой вариант:

Go-файл:

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/qml.v1"
    "os"
)

type QMLBridge struct {
    Login    string
    Password string
}

func (b *QMLBridge) Set(login string, password string) {
    b.Login = login
    //qml.Changed(b, &b.Login) // - оказалось, что не нужно
    b.Password = password
    //qml.Changed(b, &b.Password) // - оказалось, что не нужно
    fmt.Println("QMLBridge.Set", b)
}

func main() {
    if err := qml.Run(run); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func run() error {
    engine := qml.NewEngine()

    engine.On("quit", func() {
        os.Exit(0)
    })

    controls, err := engine.LoadFile("rustack.qml")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    context := engine.Context()

    context.SetVar("bridge", &QMLBridge{})

    window := controls.CreateWindow(nil)
    window.Show()
    window.Wait()
    return nil
}
```

QML-файл:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWnd
    visible: true
    title: "rustack"
    width: 630
    height: 360

    TextField {
        z: 1; x: 8; y: 8
        id: edLogin

    }

    TextField {
        z: 1; x: 8; y: 28
        id: edPass
    }

    Button {
        text: qsTr("click me")
        z: 1; x: 8; y: 48
        onClicked: {
            bridge.set(edLogin.text, edPass.text);
            console.log(bridge.login);
            console.log(bridge.password);
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Рискну предположить, что у Вас метод `Set` принимает 3 аргумента, а Вы передаёте ему два - и всё ломается на этом моменте. Ибо количество аргументов должно соответствовать.